# Playing YouTube Videos using mediaplayer of eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, video, youtube

There are many controls to play youtube videos in eclipse like `WebView`, `YouTubePlayerView`, `VideoView` etc.

My doubt is can we play it using media player? Found that, url having extension like `.mp4` can play using media player. But when tried with youtube video url it shows an error `Start Called in state 0` .

```
if(isYTFlag){ //if youtube url

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoURL);
        }
        else{ //local mp4

            afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(Integer.parseInt(videoURL));
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
        }
```

Please help to verify

Comment: post your code here so that someone wil be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another working code

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);

VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
Uri uri=Uri.parse("rtsp://r2---sn-a5m7zu76.c.youtube.com/
Ck0LENy73wIaRAnTmlo5oUgpQhMYESARFEgGUg5yZWNvbW1lbmRhdGlvbnIhAWL2kyn64K6aQtkZVJdTxRoO88HsQjpE1a8d1GxQnGDmDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp");
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.requestFocus();

videoView.start();}
```

activity_video_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"


android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[YouTube Andorid Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v) {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHHn52KhBkQ")));
}}});
```

In this solution you can directly pass the youtube video url to the  Intent which we want to play into media player.

For playing video try this link [Playing(Streaming) video with MediaPlayer](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/03/streaming-video-mediaplayer.html)

Use your videoUrl instead of their 3gp video url.

Comment: I have tried with both of these. both are working . But I need to know can we implement it using media player. That was my question .

Answer (score -1):

You can play the video using media player easily like below.
Player.java file

```
        public class Player extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
                    OnPreparedListener {
                private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
                private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
                private SurfaceView vidSurface;
                String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
                String videoSrc = "http://bffmedia.com/bigbunny.mp4";
                String videoToPlay = "rtsp://v6.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQkDsLHya4-Z9hMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYKX4k4uBjbOiUQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp";

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
                    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
                    vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
                    vidHolder.addCallback(this);

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoToPlay);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                        int height) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            } 

       //mediaplayer.xml file



            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

                <SurfaceView
                    android:id="@+id/surfView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            </RelativeLayout>

//finally add internet permission in manifest.xml file
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I'am asking about youtube video url . not about .mp4 or .3gp files.